# Alternative to nvidia-smi for measuring GPU utilization?

Tags: gpu, nvidia, performance-testing

nVidia dropped support for all non quadro and tesla cards when it comes to using some tools and/or development libraries/tools.  I have two GTX 590s, and when I use **nvidia-smi** most queryable fields return N/A because they dropped support for this card.

Are there other tools that purport to gather this information?  Is it possible/straightforward to query this information with the SDK?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On Windows there's [NvAPI](http://developer.nvidia.com/nvapi) which works on all GPUs.

On Linux if you're running X Server you can also query some of the information (GPU temperature, clocks, unfortunately no utilization) using [nvidia-settings](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/alt-nvidia-current-settings.1.html) utility. e.g. `nvidia-settings -q all`

For Quadro and Tesla GPUs there's [NVML](http://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-management-library-nvml)/[nvidia-smi](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/nvidia-system-management-interface) that works both on Linux and Windows 64.

Answer (score 6):

Although this is a very old question, I'm going to leave this here in case someone with the same issue stumble upon this. Nvidia-settings still forwards the GPU usage stat through -q [gpu:X]/GPUUtilization. it's very slow compared to nvidia-smi, but it's still better than not knowing. Either way, I wrote a script to put this and a few other common stats in a concise and readable way.
[Here it is for those who want it.](http://pastebin.com/ahj2z7bS)

Comment: The gpu utlization is still not included using this approach

Answer (score 5):

GPUstat outputs with colorful one-liners. It's implemented in Python and it has a test suite if you feel like tweaking it.

https://github.com/wookayin/gpustat

Answer (score 0):

I Would Suggest You Use MSI Afterburner Windows Application  Link-https://www.msi.com/page/afterburner
As You Execute Your Programm The Clocks will go Up
and normally it will be idle numbers 
I think this is the easy way if u don't wanna go for those commands and stuff 
and there are many options to see your GPU statistics I Hope It Helps 
Thankyou And GoodLuck

[Before Executing Your Programm It Should Be Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t11tj.png)

[And While It's Executing It Should Be Looking Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLTmC.jpg)